# How to exclude customer import in data migration tool

Tags: magento2, migration, data

Can anyone help me on how to setup the data migration tool do not transfer the customer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For excluding customer during migration, follow below step

1) go to this directory `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/YourM1Version/config.xml`

2) in this file you will see `Customer Attributes Step` step in `data` and `delta` node

3) comment out that step and your customer will not migrate during first and incremental migration

Hope this answer help you